# Jquery Switch text to input field when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a span with text, and i want to listen with jquery if the visitor clicks the text it should replace that text with a input field (which is hidden from start). If the visitor leaves the input field empty and puts it out of focus it should hide the input and show the text again.

Help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

This is the current code i have:

```
$("span").click(function() {
 $(this).hide();
 $("input").toggle();  
});
```

Comment: In order to get answers on this site, you must have tried something on your own, and then ask a specific question where you got stuck.

Comment: @rac there are tons of question on this site which are  already have answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to created a hidden element if you're moving things around in the DOM. You can use jQuery's `.replaceWith()` to do this with less code.

```
$('body').on('click', '#mySpan', function (event) {
  $( this ).replaceWith( "<input id='myInput' type='text' />" );
  $('#myInput').focus();
});

$('body').on('focusout', 'input', function (event) {
    if($(this).val() == ""){
    $( this ).replaceWith( "<span id='mySpan'>Sample Text</span>" );
    }
});
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/jX7rM/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $(function () {
   $(document).on('click', 'span', function () {
    var input = $('<input />', {
        'type': 'text',
            'name': 'unique',
            'value': $(this).html()
    });
    $(this).parent().append(input);
    $(this).remove();
    input.focus();
});

 $(document).on('blur', 'input', function () {
    $(this).parent().append($('<span />').html($(this).val()));
    $(this).remove();
});
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/hW3vk/5/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/LCVVX/)**

```
   $("span").click(function(){
    $("input").show().change(function(){
       $("span").show(); 
       $(this).hide();
    });
     $(this).hide();

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `contenteditable` span ?

set your span `contenteditable="true"`

check the fiddle.
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LQ39M/)